# NameError: name 'Period' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to create a sample dataframe from an existing dataframe with code below:

```
import datetime as dt
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'YearMonth': {0: Period('2020-07', 'M'), 1: Period('2020-06', 'M')},
 'State': {0: 'BBB', 1: 'AAA'}}
)
```

but it caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-7d7247456452> in <module>
      2 df1 = pd.DataFrame(
      3 
----> 4 {'YearMonth': {0: Period('2020-07', 'M'), 1: Period('2020-06', 'M')},
      5  'State': {0: 'BBB', 1: 'AAA'}}
      6 

NameError: name 'Period' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an import error, use `from pandas import Period`

**Either**

```
from pandas import Period
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'YearMonth': {0: Period('2020-07', 'M'), 1: Period('2020-06', 'M')},
 'State': {0: 'BBB', 1: 'AAA'}}
)
df1
```

**or**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'YearMonth': {0: pd.Period('2020-07', 'M'), 1: pd.Period('2020-06', 'M')},
 'State': {0: 'BBB', 1: 'AAA'}}
)
df1
```

**Output**

```
    YearMonth   State
0   2020-07     BBB
1   2020-06     AAA
```

Comment: np, all the best!